# How to ignore the year in google analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

So in Google Analytics I am in the organic traffic landing pages..

We use wordpress and our blog is here: /blog/

Up to last year we had /blog/year/post-name/ for the URLs however now I am trying to compare apples to apples against blog posts. so really

/blog/year/post-name/ and /blog/post-name/ are the same. Im really trying to do something like this: s/blog/201[0-9]/blog/ but it doesn't work.

I think the easiest way is to: look for /blog/ and slice out /year/ and match the landing pages so I can look at traffic reports.. that are accurate. I don't know how though. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding a search & replace filter, replacing "year" for "".

You can use these filters to consolidate data. For example, if you're getting hits from two different URLs that represent the same page (/blog/year/post-name/ and /blog/post-name/), then you can use a Search-and-replace filter to consolidate all those hits under a single hostname. In this case, you could create the following filter to strip /year/ and have all hits attributed to /blog/post-name/:

```
Filter Field: Hostname
Search String: year/
Replace String: <leave this field blank>
```

For more info see: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033162

Comment: I think the OP wants something that can be applied to existing data. Search and replace filters will only work on newly incoming data.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: Hello, like  Eike Pierstorf. I no longer have /blog/year/post-name/ - its only /blog/post-name/ though how do I use the search and replace filter? I don't see that here in Analytics?

Comment: The best option in that case will be to create a view of the data, and apply the filter to that view. See: http://www.practicalecommerce.com/articles/70250-Google-Analytics-Using-Views-and-Filters-to-Understand-Visitors. Remember to always keep a default view with unfiltered data.